# Are the districts inside the walls 'Elodia'?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Spoilers ahead for those who have not read the latest manga chapters (86 - 87).

> The latest chapters take place in the territory under the
>  "Marley government". The oppression of Elodians and their origin is the current theme. It is known that King Fritz took the Commander power and the majority of Elodians to safely retreat in an island. He used the Titan serum to transform people and build the walls. Can we derive that this territory, inside the walls (Sheena, Rose, Maria), is Elodia?

Comment: Yes. in particular, note that a guard tells Grice to run from the ocean to the walls

Comment: It's not completely clear, what was original meaning of "Elodia". We know, there was "Elodian Empire" before, but it is unclear now - was it just name, or was it somehow tied to some geographical territory. So, if it is just a name, we can call land within walls as "Elodia", since it is last remnant of Elodian Empire. If it was based on geographical name, I suppose, it's clear, that only original Elodia (city, country, or whatever it is) may be called so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

yes the walls are built inside paradi island where king fritz of elodia had run away after the Mare won the war against titans. I think this wall is supposed to serve as protection against Mare but the chapter havent explained it yet.